# Where to put an asset file to be accessible for an application?

Tags: android

Got some updates recently, i.e. moved from Eclipse to Android Studio and started using Gradle. Besides, my target API got updated from 16 to 20 and things are not working as they used to.

I started refactoring a part of my application responsible for fetching a database file. But LogCat reports no assets in `application/app/assets` directory, (`assets` is at the same level as `src` dir), although my `dbfile.sqlite` is there.

As I checked, I have the following things among assets:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
String[] assetFile = assetManager.list("");

for (int i = 0; i < assetFile.length; i++) {
Log.d(PTAG, "Assets found [" + i + "]: " + assetFile[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
D/MainActivity﹕ Assets found [0]: images
D/MainActivity﹕ Assets found [1]: sounds
D/MainActivity﹕ Assets found [2]: webkit
```

Nothing about databases. Do you know where to put my database file and how to provide the application with it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, Ladies and Gentlemen. I got the answer.

If you make your application backwards compatible and import libraries from `com.android.support`, check subdirectories in that folder: you'll probably have `appcompat-v7` and/or `support-v4`. And in those directories you'll find also `assets` folders: `assetManager.list()` from my example refers to them.

Long story short: if you plan to use predefined assets in API 4 and/or API 7, make sure your assets are copied to respective subdirectories beneath `com.android.support`.

Answer (score 0):

In a classic Android Studio project, assets go in an `assets/` directory in your `main` sourceset, or in another sourceset if appropriate. So, if your Android Studio project has your app in an `app/` module of the project, the assets go in `app/src/main/assets/`. They will then be blended in with the assets from other sourcesets in your project, plus those contributed from Android library projects, and will be bundled into your APK.

[Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsAssets-AndroidStudio) that uses `SQLiteAssetHelper` for packaging a database with an app. It has the database in the `databases/` directory within `app/src/main/assets/`. The resulting APK has the database right where you would expect:

[image: Android APK, Built By Android Studio, Showing Assets]

`SQLiteAssetHelper` is able to pick up the asset as you would expect.

Note that this project uses `appcompat-v7` (and therefore `support-v4` through the transitive dependency).

Now, you *can* have your assets located elsewhere if you prefer, but then you will need to teach Gradle where to find them. For example, [my CWAC-RichTextUtils project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richtextutils) shares assets between the `richtextutils` library's tests (in `androidTest`) and a separate `demo` module. Rather than have two copies of those assets, I have one at the project level, and I point each module's configuration to those assets in their `build.gradle` files:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['../testAssets']
    }
}
```