# Assets (database) are not copied to application database directory

Tags: android, assets

Once I launched my application I got an exception saying the app couldn't find proper table in a database. After I checked via Android Device Monitor, the correct database wasn't present in `databases` directory of my application. However, it was there in the `app/assets` directory. What has happened?

Answer (score 0):

> However, it was there in the app/assets directory.

That is the wrong place for assets in an Android Studio project, by default. Assets go in an `assets/` directory in a sourceset (e.g., `app/src/main/`). If you want to have your `assets/` be off of the module root, you can, but you will need to configure `build.gradle` to tell it where to find the assets, probably via:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to link this behavior with upgrade of Support Libraries. When you change the version you use in your application editing `build.gradle` file and you use Support Libraries (`appcompat-vx`, `support-vx`), then you have to copy assets to `app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/[library]/[version from build.gradle]/assets` to make them visible for your application.

Also, remember about wiping out your emulator device before launching your application with new settings.

This issue was also reported here: [Where to put an asset file to be accessible for an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345818/where-to-put-an-asset-file-to-be-accessible-for-an-application), but information about library upgrade is missing there.